# Xamarin debugger stops after deploy in VS 2015 Community edition

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have recently begun my development in Xamarin on Visual Studio and was able to develop 2 small applications in `KitKat`. Recently there was a mandatory update needed for my emulator which got automatically upgraded to `Marshmallow`. After the update, I am facing problem with the debugger.

I think the Debugger fails to connect to my emulator, but dont know what changes to do, to get the debugger working again.

**Explanation:**

On debugging the code with **KitKat(4.4)XXHDPI** phone emulator error message displayed on log as follows:

> Could not connect to the debugger.
>
> InspectorDebugSession(0): Disposed
>
> InspectorDebugSession(0): HandleTargetEvent: TargetExited**

[image]

However, on debugging with **Marshmellow(6.0)XXHDPI** phone emulator, code is getting deployed on the emulator but debugger remains disabled.

[image]

**I have tried following steps**

1. Hyper-V > Settings > processor > Compatibility > enabling Migrate to
   physical computer with different processor version
2. On VS 2015 community edition Solution properties and enabling deploy
   option

Screenshot:

[image]

From the screenshot:

1. The Emulator run option continues to show the Android Version, but
   the Debug Menu options listed adjacent to it remains disabled
2. The Output windows shows that the build was successful, and
   following this the output is shown in the emulator, but I am unable
   to debug the code running on the emulator

[image]

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

Created a new project on VS 2015, In this project the debugger seems to be working fine (For now). The problem still prevails in the old projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Project properties and make sure following debugging option is enabled.

> [Properties > Android Options]

[image]

Reset your import and Export settings

> [Tools > Import and Export Settings]

[image]

In the Import Export Settings, Reset the settings.

Finally, Restart your Visual Studio.